# Access certain elements in a dictionary in order to perform calculations on them

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've currently managed to build up a dictionary of results, where the key is the specimen, and the values are different readings taken. So far, my dictionary looks like this:

```
specimen_id = [spec_1, spec_2]

my_dict = {'spec_1': [[4.276171114103283, 4.216314490117101, 4.200231488212351], [36.456192134864246, 36.61209395933328, 36.73806121212328], [35.544401317411655, 35.72775122320909, 35.728258225516406]], 
'spec_2': [[4.252633201087422, 4.19541914243176, 4.204273679608983], [36.456192134864246, 36.578691493906085, 36.69502654467063], [37.05449295426373, 37.05570996715497, 37.07813832583326]]}
```

Every entry in the dictionary will have the same number of rows and columns in each nested list. I know I can split up the dictionary into keys and values like this:

```
for specimen_id, value in my_dict.items():
              print(specimen_id, ':', value)
```

But say I wanted to perform a calculation taking the average of the two specimens, of just the last element in each nested list, row by row in the dictionary, how would I do this? I know if I split it up into separate nested lists by specimen, I could access the elements by using something like a for loop, with x as a counter and then [x][2] to get the values, but I'm a bit confused here. Is there some way of splitting up the two keys into separate lists?

If I had separate nested lists, I know I could do it like this:

```
spec_1 = [[4.276171114103283, 4.216314490117101, 4.200231488212351], [36.456192134864246, 36.61209395933328, 36.73806121212328], [35.544401317411655, 35.72775122320909, 35.728258225516406]]

spec_2 = [[4.276171114103283, 4.216314490117101, 4.200231488212351], [36.456192134864246, 36.61209395933328, 36.73806121212328], [35.544401317411655, 35.72775122320909, 35.728258225516406]]


averages = []
for x in range(len(spec_1)):
    
    avg = (spec_1[x][2] + spec_2[x][2]) / 2
    
    averages.extend([avg])
    
print(averages)

[4.200231488212351, 36.73806121212328, 35.728258225516406]
```

However, the number of specimen nested lists may change, so I need to factor that in too.

Comment: In the end, you have something that looks like a 3D array: specs, rows, cols. You should considere using `numpy` which is great at processing multi-dimensional numerical arrays.

Comment: Please give a worked example to clarify the issue. Your reference to "last element in each list" is ambiguous as you have nested lists

Comment: Apologies, I have reworded the question to include the nested lists.

Comment: I have also included a working example if I had seperate nested lists.

Answer (score 1):

It's convoluted but you can do this with a list comprehension like this:

`averages = [sum(pair) / len(pair) for pair in list(zip(*[[sublist[-1] for sublist in lst] for spec, lst in my_dict.items()]))]`

To explain what's going on:
`[sublist[-1] for sublist in lst]` gets the last item of each sublist.

This is wrapped in another list which does that for every spec and lst in your dictionary.

The `zip` function combines these pairwise, so it will take the last item of the first sublist of spec 1 and pair it with the last item of the first sublist of spec 2 and so on.

This then needs casting back into a list.

And then the outermost `sum(pair) / len(pair)` bit is getting the mean of each list.

I think that works and I hope I've understood what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This works perfect, thank you! And thanks for getting through my explanation, I know it might have been a bit difficult, so I really appreciated it

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
my_dict = {
    'spec_1': [
        [4.276171114103283, 4.216314490117101, 4.200231488212351],
        [36.456192134864246, 36.61209395933328, 36.73806121212328],
        [35.544401317411655, 35.72775122320909, 35.728258225516406]
    ],
    'spec_2': [
        [4.252633201087422, 4.19541914243176, 4.204273679608983],
        [36.456192134864246, 36.578691493906085, 36.69502654467063],
        [37.05449295426373, 37.05570996715497, 37.07813832583326]
    ]
}

sums = None

for count, v in enumerate(my_dict.values(), 1):
    if sums is None:
        sums = [0.0] * len(v[0])
    for j, n in enumerate(v):
        sums[j] += n[-1]

if sums:
    print([v/count for v in sums]) # type: ignore
```

**Output:**

```
[4.202252583910667, 36.716543878396955, 36.40319827567483]
```

**Notes:**

This code could be shortened if the dimensions of the lists are known in advance but it's probably safer to figure it out at runtime